# Store data in workflow before bookmarking for use on resume

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Is it possible, somehow, to persist some information in a workflow activity for use on resuming.

Basically I have a stock standard Workflow activity, I call a service which gets a list of Ids back.

This is an example...

```
public class MyGoDoStuffActivity: NativeActivity<bool>
{
    public InArgument<int> VersionId { get; set; }
    public int[] Jobs { get; set; }

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        var container = context.GetExtension<IContainer>();
        var versionId = context.GetValue(VersionId);

        using (var service = container.Resolve<IJobsService>())
        {
            Jobs = service.StartJobs(versionId);

            context.CreateBookmark("Bookmark_Wait_For_Jobs_VersionId_" + versionId, BookmarkCallbackResult);
        }
    }

    private void BookmarkCallbackResult(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object value)
    {
        var container = context.GetExtension<IContainer>();
        var versionId = context.GetValue(VersionId);

        using (var service = container.Resolve<IJobsService>())
        {
            var status = service.HaveAllJobsCompleted(Jobs);

            if (!status) 
            {
                context.CreateBookmark("Bookmark_Wait_For_Jobs_VersionId_" + versionId, BookmarkCallbackResult);
                return;
            }
        }

        context.SetValue(Result, true);
    }
}
```

Something sort of like below...

Bookmarking, resuming, all that stuff works, but I can't figure out how to persist some additional information for use on resuming a bookmark.

The value on resume could be useful if I could update the job status and bookmark while I wait for the next status change.

Comment: Uh, [variables?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489456(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Will - I tried with In/OutArguments but they didn't seem to persist the modified values so they are lost on resume.

Comment: Not arguments. Variables.  And they are rehydrated on resume.